проблема с отправкой modal боту
@Bot.listen("on_button_click")
    async def help_listener(inter: MessageInteraction):

...
            elif inter.component.custom_id[4:] == 'verify':
                class MyModal(disnake.ui.Modal):
                    def __init__(self):
                        super().__init__(
                            title=f"Верификация",
                            custom_id="ver",
                            components=[
                            disnake.ui.TextInput(
                                label="Киллы",
                                placeholder="Количество киллов...",
                                custom_id="kills",
                                style=disnake.TextInputStyle.short,
                                required=True,
                                max_length=7,
                            )],
                        )

                async def callback(self, inter: disnake.ModalInteraction):
                    print(inter.text_values['kills'])
                    print(inter.text_values.items())
                    kills = (list(rank['role'] for rank in load(open('data.json', encoding='utf-8'))['ranks'] if rank['kills'] * 1000 < inter.text_values) or [None])[-1]
                    print(kills)
            await inter.response.send_modal(MyModal())

когда я нажимаю в дикорде кнопку отправить в modal окне, бот мне ничего в консоли не принтит и ничего не проиходит в самом коде, но в дискорде в этом же modal появляется
